# Create Area to put Modules in

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I've got an issue where I want to create an area to pull modules in.

I copy/paste my own code for the email template inside. I found docs where it is said, that I need to define `role="module"` and `role="module-content"` but that doesn't seem to work properly, because I am not able to pull modules inside that defined area.
The only time it worked was, when I set `role="modules-container"` aswell but that erased the code of the `<head>` part, because I defined it on `<body>`. Defining it on `<html>` did also not work.

Here is roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- content of header -->

<div role="module">
<div role="module-content">
</div>
</div>

<!-- content of footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody give me an example how the nesting is supposed to be, so that I can create a template, that can be edited in Design Tool and takes in modules?